# Implementation of NumPy exponential function

Tags: python, numpy, exp

I'm trying to perform an evaluation of total floating-point operations (FLOPs) of a neural network.

My problem is the following. I'm using a sigmoid function. My question is how to eval the FLOPs of the exponential function. I'm using Tensorflow which relies on NumPy for the exp function.

I tried to dig into the Numpy code but didn't find the implementation ... I saw some subjects here talking about fast implementation of exponential but it doesn't really help.

My guess is that it would use a Taylor implementation or Chebychev.

Do you have any clue about this? And if so an estimation of the amount of FLOPs. I tried to find some references as well on Google but nothing really standardized ...

Thank you a lot for your answers.

Comment: Most likely, the implementation used will be the C math library.

Comment: I suppose this depends on how tensorflow was compiled and built. Remember that x86 has `F2XM1` and `FYL2X` instructions that compute `2^x` and `y*log2(x)` respectively and can be considered as a single floating point operation each

Comment: The default implementation of `exp` in numpy is taken from C's math.h: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c900978d5e572d96ccacaa97af28e2c5f4a0b137/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h.src#L418

Depending on architecture I think they have custom SIMD versions used in loops that will be faster (and you probably want to use those).

Answer (score 1):

I looked into it for a bit and what i found is that numpy indeed uses the C implementation as seen [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4f1541e1cb68beb3049a21cbdec6e3d30c2afbbb/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h.src#L451-L471).

Tensorflow though doesnt use nmpy implementation, instead it uses the `scalar_logistics_op`function from the C++ library called Eigen. The source for that can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/master/Eigen/src/Core/functors/UnaryFunctors.h#L1060).

Comment: Many thanks for this. I realize that sigmoid function requires a lot of operations to be derived now (much more than ReLU) haha. Most NN papers do not often take this aspect in consideration ...